# Jenkins windows slave online but no builds running

Tags: windows, jenkins, jenkins-agent

We recently upgraded jenkins to 2.32.2.6. After the upgrade all the Non-Windows VM are up and running while we are facing connectivity issues with Windows Slave. The slave service is up and running. The slaves are shown as online. But if build is triggered, the job says "Waiting for next Executor" though the executor is idle. We have around 400 slaves and we are facing issues with all of them. Slave executors are idle and the build queue is rising with builds waiting for Next Build Executor. Can someone please help here?

We tried rebooting the server, the slave machine, restarting the service. Nothing is helping.

Answer (score 0):

is your Jenkins out of disk space?

go to Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes
examine the `master` node to see if it is offline. It may be reporting as the master node is out of disk space.

Comment: Nope. VM has around 500GB free space and the master is node is online